# Erro ao criar form com borda firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10

Usando Delphi do *RAD Seattle update 1* ao criar um form em tempo de execução, caso o main form esteja com a propriedade BorderStyle diferente de none recebo um erro. Este problema acontece usando o firemonkey e compilando para Android.

Para reproduzir o erro é simples, basta criar uma aplicação *firemonkey*, incluir dois formulários, não permitir criação automática, no main `form` configurar o `BorderStyle` diferente de `none` e chamar a criação do segundo `form`.

*Erro Apresentado*:

> ```
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:Only the
> original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
> ```

*Segue o código:*

```
procedure TfrmAgendamento.lstProdutosItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  if not assigned(frmExpedicao) then
    frmExpedicao := tfrmExpedicao.Create(nil);
  frmExpedicao.Show;
end;
```

Comment: coloque o seu código para analisarmos.

Comment: Ao aparecer o erro, dê ctrl+c na mensagem e poste aqui, se não der tire print e poste, ai conseguimos analisar melhor.

Comment: David o erro é exatamente este que coloquei no post.